# MATLAB cell2mat concatenating numbers together

Tags: matlab, cell

I'm trying to plot something in a cell array, so I'm trying to convert one of the columns to a matrix.

I pulled out the column from the cell array and tried to do cell2mat on it to turn it into a matrix. However, cell2mat seems to just turn it into one long character array.

```
site(:,4)'; % Pull out column 4 from the cell array
cell2mat(ans); % Attempt to convert the cell into a matrix
```

The first part of the code gives me:
10.4  10.1  7.9  8.2

The second part of the code gives me:
10.410.17.98.2

How can I make the cell into a matrix that I can use to plot a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your cell array contains strings, is that correct? In that case you don't use `cell2mat`, but  `str2double`:

```
str2double(site(:,4).')
```

For example:

```
>> site = {'1',   '2',   '3',   '4';
           '1.1', '2.1', '3.1', '4.1'};
>> str2double(site(:,4).')
ans =
    4.0000    4.1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x is your abstract:

```
y = site(:,4)';
```

You can now make it a vector and plot it as such:

```
plot([y{:}])
```

Comment: The issue is that conversion to double from cell is not possible and to plot, MATLAB seems to require double. That's why I'm trying to convert to a matrix first because cells can't be turned into doubles directly (as far as I know).